# Can ImageResizer rewrite extensions so that the file extension follows the format=jpg querystring?

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer, google-image-search

I've been using most of the following Global.asax (Application_Start) code with good effect for some time now ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003002/is-using-config-current-pipeline-rewrite-the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-wat)). I've configured it this way to serve up watermarked images on certain directories when the requests are initiated externally (hotlinked/direct requests).

```
  //ImageResizer
  Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite += delegate(IHttpModule mysender, HttpContext context, IUrlEventArgs ev)
  {
     if (context.Request.UrlReferrer == null || (context.Request.UrlReferrer != null && context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host != "www.mydomain.com"))
     {
        //File has been requested from outside of the target domain, so see if it meets criteria for watermarking
        string folder1 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/products");
        string folder2 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/product-showcase");
        if (ev.VirtualPath.StartsWith(folder1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || ev.VirtualPath.StartsWith(folder2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
           //Image is within the targeted folders. If the requested file is jpg, change extension to png
           if (Path.GetExtension(ev.VirtualPath) == ".jpg") ev.VirtualPath = Path.ChangeExtension(ev.VirtualPath, ".png");

           //Estimate final image size, based on the original image being 300x300. 
           System.Drawing.Size estimatedSize = ImageBuilder.Current.GetFinalSize(new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300), new ResizeSettings(ev.QueryString));
           if (estimatedSize.Width > 100 || estimatedSize.Height > 100)
           {
              //It's over 100px, apply watermark and change the ouput format
              ev.QueryString["watermark"] = "style";
              ev.QueryString["bgcolor"] = "ffffff";
              ev.QueryString["format"] = "jpg";
           }
        }
     }
  };
```

However, I just modified my web pages so that my product images are served up with the addition of the &format=jpg query string.  I understand that a proper MIME type is served up to the web browser, and that is really cool and all, but what about the filename?
e.g. /images/products/widget1.png?watermark=c&format=jpg still refers to a png image even though the served format is jpg.  What concerns me is that scrapers or image aggregators like Google Images might either  1) want to strip the URL down to the filename or 2) take the MIME type into account and re-reference it by changing the extension.  I'm not sure what Google Images actually does with a URL like above and want to handle both scenarios. [Maybe if I knew, I could target this situation better]

To handle Scenario 2, I just added the Path extension check above and everything is handled smoothly.  BTW I only have .png images in the target directories.

For Scenario 1, external requests for the .png file go through, but the file is actually encoded as a .jpg and that's the part that blows.  I wish I could rewrite the extension.  I tried doing that using Response.Redirect, but since I'm working inside Application_Start, I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go  complicating your code, make sure you know what you're trying to fix. As far as I know, the issues you describe are theoretical, and don't exist. If you can explain the *actual problem you've seen and are trying to solve*, that would be helpful.

Rewriting does nothing to alter what browsers see - it happens within the server. Only HTTP redirection will change the URL visible to the browser or Google, and that is highly inadvisable since it doubles the latency.

You can affect the filename used when downloading or saving an image by using the [Content-disposition HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header), but this won't affect the browser URL or SEO.

Comment: Your points are well-taken.  I will need to wait for enough spidering to see what the more lasting effects may be.  I was trying to anticipate while coding.